# When a PPA has a package of the same name in the Ubuntu Software Center, which one is downloaded by apt?

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, package-management, ppa

If a PPA in your `sources.list` has a package of the same name in the Ubuntu Software Center, which one shows up in the Software Center? Likewise, which package is downloaded via `apt-get install`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whichever repo has the latest version of the package is the one shown in the Ubuntu Software center and downloaded with `apt-get install`. It is like this by default, but can be changed in the Software Repositories window.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to change the default behavior and into what it can be changed? Thanks!

Comment: This is *not completely* correct, you can set priority of a source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Answer (score 14):

### Package priority

The priorities of package sources is defined in the local package configuration.
This configuration can be inspected with `apt-cache policy`.

Here is an example of what `apt-cache policy` shows for the package `git` that is available in the Ubuntu main package repository, and in a PPA, and the PPA version is currently installed:

```
$ apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: 1:2.1.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 1:2.1.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.1.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.9.1-1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

The numbers in front of the URLs specify the priority. The package from a source with the highest priority is preferred, if there is only one source with this priority.

### Newer package of equal priority

If there are multiple entries of the highest priority, as it is the case here, the newer version is preferred.

### Change priorities

To change the priorities to prefer a specific version, exceptions rules can be defined in `/etc/apt/preferences`. Locking a package to a fixed version is called "pinning".
See [PinningHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).